# SQLite - Is it possible to use the group_concat function in the same query but 'GROUP BY' different criteria?

Tags: function, sqlite, group-by, group-concat

I have been searching online with no luck to see if it possible to have a single query that contains two group_concat with two different 'GROUP BY' criteria. Basically I want to have a query that group_concats one column based on one set of criteria and then another column that is group_concat with a different set of criteria.

As an example, if I have the below table:

| ID | Country | Item | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | B | Chair |
| 2 | UK | B | Chair |
| 2 | UK | B | Car |
| 3 | NZ | A | Car |
| 1 | NZ | A | Bicycle |
| 3 | USA | A | Bicycle |

If I wanted to group_concat the Product column by 'ID' AND 'Country' in one column and group_concat the Product column by 'Country' only in another column how could I do this in the one query. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance, I'm still a novice user of SQLite and it would be good to know if this is possible.

Comment: What is your expected output for this sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with GROUP_CONCAT() window function instead of GROUP_CONCAT() aggregate function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Country,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Product) OVER (
         PARTITION BY Country 
         ORDER BY Product
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) products_by_country,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Product) OVER (
         PARTITION BY ID, Country 
         ORDER BY Product
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) products_by_id_country
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8e4c19d30bb547373f3517d849067490).

Comment: Thank you! This is really great! Are there any issues if I was to use this alongside a group_concat() aggregate function? Apologies for the late reply

Comment: Also do you have any additional information about how the ROWS BETWEEN works? I've looked over the SQLITE (https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) documentation and it's a little confusing

Comment: @user5553440 for your 1st question, it depends on the requirement. It's possible to mix aggregate and window functions. For your 2nd question, I believe that the examples in the documentation are good but you could also take a look at SQL Server's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#rows-or-range